# checking is a point lies inside the area enclosed by multiple equations using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A friend of mine asked me this problem, given a point, i want to check if its inside the area described by four different points. So, i got this idea which i learnt from linear algebra. so, this is my approach.

Consider these four points as four different vectors.  Any linear combination of these four vector's will span the entire area they are supposed to span.(Probably this is my mistake. please correct me). So, what i can do is, take these four points, put them as a matrix and do the following.

AX = U

where A is consists of the 4 different vectors. X is any point or any transformation that would lead to the final vector v which satisfies these four equations. I am trying to solve it, but, i can't. Let me give the example i am trying.

i have four points (0,0), (3,0), (0,3), (3,3). here is where i got confused. In Linear algebra, i never took more than enough equations and found the equation. Like, we always try to find the hyperplane that satisfies the linear equations.

I might be totally wrong about my approach. But, want to know why. which concept of linear algebra i am violating. Or, is these a way to think of using these four different points as linear combination and try to get any point that lies inside the area enclosed?

Comment: If you search this site or the internet you will find several algorithms. See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: @sammygerbil, thanks. But, i wanted to know what's wrong in my thinking. I think, i have seriously misunderstood the usage of matrices or linear combinations

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your method, and I am not sure that I would be able to answer even if I did. Perhaps if you make your explanation clearer someone else might be able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only mention linear combination of $4$ points. This is not sufficient.

What you need is convex combination.

Suppose the columns of $A$ consists of the $4$ points which are the vertices of the region, if $U$ is inside the convex hull, then we can find $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^4, \lambda \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i = 1, A\lambda = U$.

This can be solved by using a linear programming solver.